# Is it possible to use navigation properties with no foreign key constraint?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a system in place that has a collection of `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` items that specify how data should be sorted.

So, for example, on entry might look something like this.

```cs
Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> sort = q => q.OrderBy(r => Arrival);
```

And then it gets used to sort my query.

```cs
var railcars = DbContext.Railcars
    .Where(r => r.ArrivalDate != null)
    .OrderBy(sort)
    .ToList();
```

This system works well. However, I now need to write a `Func<T>` that has a join to a table with no foreign key. So I end up with something like this.

```cs
Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> sort = q => q.OrderBy(r => r.InboundQuantity
    - DbContext.Transfers
        .Where(t => t.FromId == r.Id && t.FromType == TransferType.Railcar)
        .Sum(t => t.Quantity)
    + DbContext.Transfers
        .Where(t => t.ToId == r.Id && t.ToType == TransferType.Railcar)
        .Sum(t => t.Quantity));
```

The problem is I have no reference to `DbContext` here. And it would take a major rewrite or dozens and dozens of pages to change the way this works, just for this one case. If I had a foreign key, I could use navigation properties and there'd be no issue.

Is there any way to use something like navigation properties when there is no foreign key. Or any other way to do what I need without needing a reference to `DbContext`?

##### Additional Information

My entities look something similar to this. The `FromId` and `ToId` columns in the `Transfers` table are the "foreign keys". But the tables they reference depend on the values of the `FromType` and `ToType` columns. They will represent a foreign key to the `Railcars` table only when the corresponding type is `TransferType.Railcar`.

```cs
public enum TransferType
{
    Storage = 0,
    Railcar = 1,
    Truck = 2,
    Ship = 3,
}

public class Transfer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TransferType FromType { get; set; }
    public int FromId { get; set; }

    public TransferType ToType { get; set; }
    public int ToId { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Railcar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RailcarNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Arrival { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Departure { get; set; }
}

// Also have Storage, Truck and Ship tables that the foreign
// keys could refer to, instead of Railcar
```

Comment: Yes, configure your DbContext and types with that setup and it will do the join despite there being no FK configured at the DB level. Obviously this will include the danger of there being no integrity constraint so a runtime exception could occur.

Comment: @jamesSampica: Given that the actual foreign key could be to one of several different tables (based on the `FromType` and `ToType` properties), I have no idea what that would look like.

Comment: The Railcars type will need a nav property defined that goes to Transfers. Hard to give better advice since I don't understand the data very well.

Comment: @jamesSampica: I've appended some additional details to my question. Normally, I would add a foreign key by adding an `int` and then an entity column with a similar name (like `int UserId; User User;`). But here, I'm not sure how to define the reference. Also, ideally, I would have references to the different table that these columns could refer to.

Comment: I see now. IME selecting tables dynamically is something not really supported by EF, or at least in a way that isn't very convoluted or brittle. Maybe someone else has a clever idea.